# Why forkJoin is not working for observers?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, angular8

I have tried to emulate server requests:

```
const _blocks$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
const _fields$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
```

Then I run two observers:

```
 of(true)
      .pipe(delay(1000))
      .subscribe(() => {
        _blocks$.next(["blocks"]);
      });

    of(false)
      .pipe(delay(5000))
      .subscribe(() => {
        _fields$.next(["fields"]);
      });
```

Somewhere in application I try to listen and join observers:

```
forkJoin(_blocks$, _fields$).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

Why I  dont get `console.log(data);` after execution?

My issue is to listen all requests to server, and when they are completed to join result using forkJoin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can complete the observables after the first emmition with `take(1)`, and then the `forkJoin` will emit successfully.

```js
const _blocks$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
const _fields$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

const blocks$ = this._blocks$.asObservable().pipe(take(1));
const fields$ = this._fields$.asObservable().pipe(take(1));

forkJoin(blocks$, fields$).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `forkJoin` waits until all streams complete, and neither of your subjects ever does.

You could use `combineLatest` instead.

Comment: Yes, I need `forkJoin` to await until all responses finished on the page, then get result, why it does not work

Comment: I answered that.

Comment: Coud you explain combineLatest

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
let _blocks$ = new Observable<number>();
let _fields$ = new Observable<number>();

   _blocks$ = of(1).pipe(delay(1000));
    _fields$ = of(2).pipe(delay(5000));

    _blocks$.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("blocks");
    });

    _fields$.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("fields");
    });

    forkJoin(_blocks$, _fields$).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
```

Consumers can subscribe anywhere in application on `_blocks$` and `_fields$`